# Server Unresponsive: Hardware Swapped, No Hints from Window Logs

Tags: sql-server, email

We have a Windows SQL Server: Intel Xeon E3-1240 Quad Core, 8GB RAM, 500GB 7200 RPM SATA hard drive.

The Server becomes unresponsive once every 2-3 days. But nothing "unusual" shows up in Windows logs. We even set up Performance Monitoring Scripts: but our resource usage is no more than 10%.

1. Is there any way we can check out from the Server on what is bringing it down?
2. Sometimes, when we approve outgoing email alerts, which go to some 1200 people via mailenable installed on the Server, the Server becomes unresponsive. But the server of this capacity should be able to handle these emails. Is there something which we are overlooking?

Comment: If this only happens when you're running mailenable, I suggest that you open a support ticket with mailenable. Especially if no events are being generated.

Comment: what counters are you logging for performance?

Comment: Thanks. The counters for logging performance are:  Memory/Available 
Avg. Disk Queue Length
Disk Bytes/Transfer
Disk Writes/Sec
Disk Reads/Sec
%Processor Time
DPCs Queued/Sec

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshootnig server hangs is a difficult task where ther is no crash or event log to go on.  Monitoring is yor only real help here.  You should probably follow the guidance in this series of articles from the Windows performance team.

[Troubleshooting Server Hangs 1](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/09/25/troubleshooting-server-hangs-part-one.aspx)
[Troubleshooting Server Hangs 2](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2008/05/06/troubleshooting-server-hangs-part-two.aspx)
[Troubleshooting Server Hangs 3](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2008/05/09/troubleshooting-server-hangs-part-three.aspx)
[Troubleshooting Server Hangs 4](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2008/05/16/troubleshooting-server-hangs-part-four.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Another useful tool to have in place is Wireshark.  It allows inspection of all network traffic and filtering by protocol and ip adrress and hostname.  It is free and allows a look behind the scenes at the type of data and requests flowing to and from the server.

Comment: What hardware did you swap out?
Is this server a VM?